# PDOException on Windows Server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm fairly new to MySQL and PHP, so bear with me. After some research, I found out...much to my distress...that apparently my site is hosted on a Windows server (by default) on GoDaddy which doesn't support PDO.

I just recently switched all database calls to use prepared statements through recommendation from another question I posted. I now find out that these aren't running and I'm getting a nasty error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in D:\Hosting\8446415\html\ROOTFOLDER\php\Connect.php:8

Stack trace: #0 D:\Hosting\8446415\html\ROOTFOLDER\php\Connect.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=HOSTNAME', 'DBNAME', 'PASSWORD') 

#1 D:\Hosting\8446415\html\ROOTFOLDER\admin.php(67): Connect->connect()
#2 {main} thrown in D:\Hosting\8446415\html\ROOTFOLDER\php\Connect.php on line 8
```

Here is Connect.php:

```
<?php
    class Connect {
        const expAddress = "HOSTNAME";
        const expUser = "USERNAME";
        const expPwd = "PASSWORD";

        function connect() {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::expAddress.';dbname='.self::expUser.';charset=UTF-8', self::expUser, self::expPwd);

            if(!$db) {
                die("<p>Could not establish a connection to the database.</p>");
                include('footer.php');  
            }
            else {
                return $db; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So what is the fix here? I don't know what is supported, and I was told to shy away from all mysql_* statements.

**I cannot upgrade my hosting account to Linux, even though that would be easiest.** Do I need to use mysqli_* statements? How would this particular call change so that the input is safe from injection?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->execute(array($user, $pass));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have `pdo_mysql` installed. Check `phpinfo()` for `pdo_mysql` ... if you know it's installed, you may just need to uncomment the `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in php.ini ...

To catch your create error and display it nicely, you can modify your code as such:

```
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::expAddress.';dbname='.self::expUser.';charset=UTF-8', self::expUser, self::expPwd);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connect Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

return $db;
```

Comment: Where can I find php.ini? Do I have to write one myself?

Comment: If you look at the output of `phpinfo()` it will tell you where your default php.ini is located.

Comment: From what I've found, it doesn't seem like I'm able to use a custom php.ini file. Do you know how to edit the original?

Comment: Once you know where the original is, open it in notepad and edit it. Save it and restart IIS.

Comment: Ahh, got it. It was the restarting IIS that I forgot to do, so the changes hadn't been realized yet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do have access to php.ini, make sure that this line is uncommented:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```